# Activerecord SQL query output

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have a fairly long SQL query in Rails:

```
Region.includes(:answers, answers: :choice)
      .where('choices.id IS NULL OR choices.id = ?', 28)
      .where('answers.id IS NULL OR answers.question_id = ?', 14)
      .group("regions.region","choices.choice").count("answers")
```

Which gives me a hash of all regions, with the choice name and answer counts, even when the count is zero. Here is the output:

```
{["East", nil]=>0, ["East Midlands", nil]=>0, ["London", nil]=>0, ["North East", nil]=>0, ["North West", nil]=>0, ["Northern Ireland", nil]=>0, ["Rest of World", "No"]=>3, ["Scotland", nil]=>0, ["South East", nil]=>0, ["South West", nil]=>0, ["Wales", nil]=>0, ["West Midlands", nil]=>0, ["Yorkshire and the Humber", nil]=>0}
```

Currently the only region with answers is 'Rest of World' which displays the Choice name 'No'.

All the other items display 'nil' as the choice name (choices.choice). How can I change the query to output the Choice name 'No' instead of nil, even though there are no answers associated to it?

Thanks

Comment: by adding a default value to your database?

Comment: To which model? I not sure this would work. The query is counting answers. Each answer is assigned a given region by region_id when it's created. I already have a default 'votes' value for the question when it's created, but this is not split by region.

Comment: ah ok, so the relation is not set. it's not that there is `NULL` as a value of `choice.choice` in the database?

Comment: Yes thats correct. I need the 'IS NULL' part in the query in order to display for all regions and choices, regardless of having count zero.

Comment: i think you will have to do that programmatically like it is described in the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's simple - use Postgres `COALESCE()`, it works the way that You supply any number of arguments and the first that yields non `NULL` value gets returned.

Try this :

```
Region.includes(:answers, answers: :choice)
      .where('choices.id IS NULL OR choices.id = ?', 28)
      .where('answers.id IS NULL OR answers.question_id = ?', 14)
      .group("regions.region","COALESCE(choices.choice, 'No')").count("answers")
```

Comment: This is great and works, is it possible to pass the instance variable in like '@choices.choice' instead of the string 'No'?

Comment: Ignore that comment. I achieved it through '#{choices.first.choice}'. Will mark as accepted. Thank you

Comment: Not sure what exactly You want to pass. Where this @choices is coming from ?